# How to extract coordinates of 3D plot in a .dat file

Tags: plotting, export, data

I want to extract coordinates of 3D plot in a `.dat` file. For example I have the following plot

```
Plot3D[Sin[3 x + y^2], {x, 0, 2  π}, {y, 0, 2  π}]
```

How can I export a `.dat` file containing three columns of numbers as

first value $\quad$$\quad$  second value $\quad$$\quad$ value of function

of the above plot.
for example

0 $\quad$$\quad$ 0 $\quad$$\quad$ 0

1 $\quad$$\quad$  2 $\quad$$\quad$ 0.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plo = Plot3D[Sin[3 x + y^2], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 15]

Export["out.dat", plo[[1, 1]]]
```

Or, if you want to export to Excel, it's just

```
Export["C:\\your path\\out.xlsx", plo[[1, 1]]]
```

Comment: How can I decrease density of the values? for example the step  0.01

Comment: Look at the Option `PlotPoints`

Comment: I did not work. Could please give me an example of using this option?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome - and thanks for the accept